# Error processing email body when using velocity script in Marketo

Tags: velocity, marketo

I'm trying to add an email script token that will take only part of the string BEFORE the opening parenthesis. So the string is "Hello (www.google.com)" then I only want "Hello".

This is for use in a Marketo email.

The code that I'm trying to use is:

```
#set ( $index = ${lead.zasset}.indexOf('(') )
#set ( $asset = ${lead.zasset}.substring(0, ${index}) )
${asset}
#end
```

But instead of it showing "Hello", it's giving me this error message:

> "Cannot get email content- An error occurred when procesing the
>   email Body!
>
> Lexical error, Encountered: "i" (105), after :
>   "." at *unset*[line 327, column 125] near
>
> </div>
>   </div> <div
>   class="spacer"
>   style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;height:30px;font-size:30px;line-height:30px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:0"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I believe the _#end_ is the problem. There is no loop or conditional to end. If there's more to the snippet, please post the whole thing.

Possibly also consider quoting the paren on the first line `.indexOf('\(')` if removing the _#end_ isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#set ( $index = ${lead.zasset.indexOf('(')} )
#set ( $asset = ${lead.zasset.substring(0, $index)} )
$asset
#end
```

You only need the *formal* notation ${...} when there are ambiguous characters around, and its curly braces should contain the whole expression.

Comment: thanks! that worked, I added an if statement to handle cases where the string is empty because without it i was still getting errors.

Comment: As a side note and for completeness, you could also get rid of the formal notation inside the #if conditions.